# string variable to open file

Tags: c++, string, file

My code should open 100 files (and do something with them) with next indexes in path like:
"c:\Naprzeme\NAPRZ100.IN" next one is "c:\Naprzeme\NAPRZ101.IN" and etc. :

```
for (int as=100;as<159;as++){
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << as;
    string cherk = ss.str();
string supremeCounter = "c:\\Naprzeme\\NAPRZ"+cherk+".IN";
fstream infile(supremeCounter);
//....other code here
}
```

and `fstream infile(supremeCounter)` returns error

```
28 31 C:\Users\talent\Documents\File.cpp [Error] no matching
 function for call to     'std::basic_fstream<char>::basic_fstream(std::string&)' 
candidates are: //(here some libs)...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fstream infile(supremeCounter.c_str());`